# '_InvalidUnpickledPCollection' object has no attribute 'windowing'

Tags: apache-beam

I am trying to create a pipeline with Apache Beam, where the first step is to center the input time series around 0 by taking the average of the input `PCollection`, then subtracting each element from the average with a `Map`. However, running the below script gives me the following error:

`'_InvalidUnpickledPCollection' object has no attribute 'windowing'`

```
import apache_beam as beam
import numpy as np
from apache_beam.testing.test_pipeline import TestPipeline


raw_input = np.array(range(1024), dtype=float) # time series is made up of floats
def run_test():
    with TestPipeline() as test_pl:
        input = test_pl | "Create" >> beam.Create(raw_input)
        avg = input | "Average" >> beam.CombineGlobally(beam.combiners.MeanCombineFn())
        centered = input | "Center" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x - beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(avg))
        test_pl.run()


run_test()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error when I run your code on https://play.beam.apache.org/. Instead, it worked as expected. However, I had to add the import for TestPipeline  (`from apache_beam.testing.test_pipeline import TestPipeline`) and instead of writing the output to `avg`, I changed this line to `input | "Average" >> beam.CombineGlobally(beam.combiners.MeanCombineFn()) | beam.Map(print)`

Comment: Sorry, I realized I left out the last line which is where the error comes from, which is when the input `PCollection` gets centered. Also added the missing import for the `TestPipeline`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing your lambda as a dedicated mapping function solves your error message, however, for reasons unknown to me the output seems to be duplicated (at least when I test this on [play.beam.apache.org](https://play.beam.apache.org/))

```
import apache_beam as beam
import numpy as np
from apache_beam.testing.test_pipeline import TestPipeline

def centering(element, average):
    return element - average

raw_input = np.array(range(1024), dtype=float) # time series is made up of floats
def run_test():
    with TestPipeline() as test_pl:
        input = test_pl | "Create" >> beam.Create(raw_input)
        avg = input | "Average" >> beam.CombineGlobally(beam.combiners.MeanCombineFn())
        centered = input | "Center" >> beam.Map(centering, beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(avg))
        centered | beam.Map(print)
        test_pl.run()

run_test()
```

As **gorilla_glue** pointed out, the reason being that we need to provide an explicit side-input variable (either by providing a method as in my code above or within the lambda, i.e., `lambda x, side_input: ...`).

Comment: I also experienced the output being printed twice on my local machine. Also, do you have an explanation for why the average value needs to be supplied as a parameter in the function, as compared to how I did it? And what does the error message in my question mean? It seemed very cryptic to me.

Comment: I' not 100% sure, but it could do with the [source code](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/_modules/apache_beam/transforms/core.html#Map) of `beam.Map`. It seems that if you provide only a lambda function, the if condition checking for a side input fails?

Comment: It's not about providing a lambda function, it's about your function having a separate parameter for the side input. I made a lambda function with signature `lambda x, av` and it fixed the error. I guess I'll just chalk it up to this being the appropriate way to provide side inputs.

Comment: I've added your explanation to my answer