# Data not getting written to Joining Column

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Following Python Apache Beam code is not writing Null Value to Bigquery field `sum_rpp_million`. All other columns are getting loaded as per expectations.

I am expecting that it should write Sum calculated at PCollection `data_sum` to all records of Pcollection `data_loading`.

Please help me in identifying where code is going wrong.

```
    data_loading = (
        p1
        | 'ReadData' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input, skip_header_lines =1)   
        | 'SplitData' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(';'))
        | 'FormatToDict' >> beam.Map(lambda x: {"country_code": x[1], "unique_code": x[2], "name": x[3], "geom": x[4], "population": None if x[5]=='' else round(float(x[5])), "households":None if x[6]=='' else round(float(x[6])), "rpp_million": float(x[7]) if x[7] != '' else None, "rppc_million": (0 if x[8]=='' else float(x[7]))+(0 if x[9]=='' else float(x[9])), "pp_million": (None if x[10]=='' else float(x[10])), "sum_rpp_million": None}) 
        )

    data_sum = (
        data_loading
        | 'ExtractColumn' >> beam.Map(lambda x: 0 if x['rpp_million']==None else x['rpp_million'])
        | 'SumFieldC2' >> beam.CombineGlobally(sum)
        | 'AddSumField' >> beam.MapTuple(lambda record, sum_c2: {**record, 'sum_rpp_million': sum_c2})
        )

    combined_data = (data_loading, data_sum) | beam.Flatten()
    
#---------------------Type = audit----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    result = (
    combined_data
        | 'Write-Audit' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                                    table='bqdata124',
                                                    dataset=dataset_id,
                                                    project=project,
                                                    schema=table_schema_Audit,
                                                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
                                                    ))
```

Currently my Code is populating data as given below :-
[image]

Expectation is Field `sum_rpp_million` should populate `Sum(rpp_million)` in all records. if value of `Sum(rpp_million)` equal to `100`, then `100` should be populated in all records under field `sum_rpp_million`

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are trying to do or what it is happening vs what you expect. Is the record being printed as expected on line 12? The problem is only noticeable on BigQuery? Can you also print `combined_data` and see what you have there after flattening both PCollections?

Comment: Print was an internal debugging  step which i have removed it now. Requirement is to calculate Sum over PCollection field 'rpp_million' (on all records) and store aggregated value as a new filed ```sum_rpp_million``` to PCollection ```data_loading```

Comment: Can you give us a mock for input and expected result please ?

Comment: Added data details also. Hopefully you will get more clarity.

Comment: Hi @VibhorGupta ,Did the answer below help you in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am a surprised why it works at all for you. If I recreate your `data_sum` I get

> TypeError: () argument after * must be an iterable, not float

since [CombineGlobally](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/combineglobally/) called with a simple `sum` returns only a single value (i.e., the sum) and `beam.MapTuple` expects a tuple as input.

Instead, If you wish to add a global sum to your data, you have to insert your `data_sum` as a [side input](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs) (similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73198009/16622985)) into a custom function, like

```
import apache_beam as beam

def insert_sum(element, global_sum):
  element['sum_rpp_million'] = global_sum
  return element

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
  data_loading = (
    pipeline
    | "init main" >> beam.Create([
    {
      'country_code': 'FR',
      'unique_code': '2A1',
      'name': 'Sartene',
      'population': 34561,
      'households': 451,
      'rpp_million': None,
      'rppc_million': 71.057
    },
    {
      'country_code': 'FR',
      'unique_code': '2A4',
      'name': 'Bastia',
      'population': 123456,
      'households': 734,
      'rpp_million': 9,
      'rppc_million': 71.057
    },
    {
      'country_code': 'FR',
      'unique_code': '2B2',
      'name': 'Ajaccio',
      'population': 6234,
      'households': 99,
      'rpp_million': -642.5,
      'rppc_million': 71.057
    },
    {
      'country_code': 'FR',
      'unique_code': '2B3',
      'name': 'Corte',
      'population': 5137,
      'households': 893,
      'rpp_million': 236.3,
      'rppc_million': 71.057
    }])
  )
  
  data_sum = (
    data_loading
    | 'ExtractColumn' >> beam.Map(lambda x: 0 if x['rpp_million']==None else x['rpp_million'])
    | beam.CombineGlobally(sum)
    #| 'AddSumField' >> beam.MapTuple(lambda record, sum_c2: {**record, 'sum_rpp_million': sum_c2})  # Causes exception!
  )
  
  combined_data = (
    data_loading
    | "AddSumToData" >> beam.Map(insert_sum, beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(data_sum))
    | beam.Map(print)
  )
```